# search result of other website

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I tried doing the method

```
form action="http://www.domain.com/search" method="GET" target="_blank"
<input type="text" name="q" size="31" maxlength="255" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
```

it work with some website but it doesnt work with

```
<form action="http://www.runningstatus.in/search" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="q" size="31" maxlength="255" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

and

```
<form action="http://www.nseindia.com/search" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="q" size="31" maxlength="255" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

i m new to this.

can anyone explain me how it work ?

Comment: `http://www.runningstatus.in/search` worked for me, `http://www.nseindia.com//search` does not exist?

Comment: could having method="POST" on the other two be causing the problem

Comment: i want to paste train no in textbox of http://runningstatus.in/      it is not working with me.                                           second one is http://www.nseindia.com/

Comment: Don't think its possible. But you could ask for trian number and date and go to results page

Comment: date is dropdown,i don't want to accept it.i  want to paste train no in textbox

Comment: You can't access dom elements of an iframe from another domain

Comment: can someone ans pls !!